# Exception handling for writedata to file for swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift2

I am creating csv file and writing a data to that file using writeData method of NSFileHandle. Apple mention method raises exception if no free space is left. My question is that how would i handle exception in swift 1.2. And what best possible way to handle memory limit issue check before writing to file?

Comment: You should upgrade your project to Swift 2.0, Swift 1.2 doesn't have exception handler

Comment: @CongTran the same is true in Swift 2. Exception is not an throwing Error, be careful  ...

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't offer exception handling. Yes, you can 'install' your own exception handler, but you are still not able to recover from an exception. What Swift 2 provides for you is error handling (not exception handling), see apple docs about do / try / catch

```
func writeData(_ data: NSData)
```

If the receiver is a file, writing takes place at the file pointer’s current position. After it writes the data, the method advances the file pointer by the number of bytes written. This method **raises an exception** if the file descriptor is closed or is not valid, if the receiver represents an unconnected pipe or socket endpoint, if no free space is left on the file system, or if any other writing error occurs.